# Reading a text file into a 2d vector. C++

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

I have a 9x8 textfile with no spaces in between the characters. How can I open this text and read it and put it into a 2d vector with characters? What i have so far is this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream in_str("inputtxt.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(in_str,line))
{}
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> replacements;
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to set it up still and adding the file into the vector

Comment: If you have fixed-size data that is known at compilation time, consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead. And then you either want an array of arrays of *characters* **or** an array of *strings*. And you need to define this *before* the loop where you add the data into the array/vector.

Comment: Give us an example of the file.

Comment: .........  .........  .........  .........  ....X....  .........  .........  .........  .........

Comment: this would be an example of the file. Each space indicates a newline

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I understand that but im still having trouble reading the file and putting it into an array or a vector

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
std::array<std::array<char, 8>, 9> characters;

std::string line;
size_t pos = 0;
while (std::getline(in_str, line))
{
    std::copy(std::begin(line), std::end(line),
              std::begin(characters[pos++]);
}
```

This will read lines from the input file, and copy all characters into the array.

***Note:*** The above code have no error handling, no checks for the input actually being valid, and most importantly of all there's no checks for going out of bounds of the arrays. If there are more lines of input than expected, or more characters per line than expected, you *will* get [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

Another possible solution, if you're happy to store strings (which of course can be accessed using array-indexing syntax like arrays/vectors), you could do e.g.

```
std::array<std::string, 9> characters;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in_str),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::begin(characters));
```

Same disclaimer as for the first code sample applies here too.